# How to ask people to reconsider their votes?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, downvotes, downvote-reason

I recently asked a fairly decent question, but at first (original, no edit), I structured it a bit incorrectly. (I had written `Java` and `pass-by-value/reference` in the same sentence, and I had only meant to clarify something, not ask that). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935589/when-does-android-serialize-objects/30936196#30936196) is the question.

Two minutes after asking the question, I got a lot of downvotes (ouch), and no comments as to why. I could tell people didn't even bother to read the question, and even an out-of-context answer!

I immediately edited the question, and after that, I got positive feedback. The person with that out-of-context answer deleted it. 
My question was genuine, and I got a good answer.

My question has negative ratings, and it not only hurts me but anyone who may come across that issue.

**Is there any way I could ask those people to reconsider their votes? I am not looking for a positive rating or more views, just an honest reconsideration form those who didn't read the full post.**

Comment: You  should certainly not put large disclaimers about this at the top of your question. The people who have already voted won't see it, and every new user will be annoyed by having to read through meta stuff before coming to the actual question. It doesn't serve any purpose and just spoils the mood further.

Comment: @deceze Of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't a way, and there shouldn't be. Otherwise there would be a lot of noise from users posting terrible questions and urging people to reverse their votes. If you don't want downvotes (and actually have a good question), make sure your first post is poignant. If your question was improved, then eventually it should get enough upvotes to appear as a 'good' question.